# webpack-dev-server enables features, then disconnects twice when using "host" option in Webpack config

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

After updating webpack-dev-server to 4.4.0 from 3.11.0, when I use the "host" option under devServer in my Webpack config file, hot reload is no longer working. My console shows WDS connecting twice and subsequently disconnecting:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
[webpack-dev-server] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
[webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled. 
[webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!
[webpack-dev-server] Trying to reconnect... 
[webpack-dev-server] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
[webpack-dev-server] Live Reloading enabled.
[webpack-dev-server] Disconnected!
```

When I remove the "host" option and revert back to "localhost," hot reload works consistently.

The devServer section of my webpack config file:

```js
devServer: {
  port: 3000,
  host: 'app.ddev.site',
  allowedHosts: 'auto',
  open: true,
  hot: true,
  proxy: {
    '/xhr': 'http://localhost:7777',
  },
},
```

Webpack package versions:

```
"webpack": "^5.61.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.4.0"
```

Scripts relating to "npm run dev":

```
"client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve --config=config/webpack.dev.js",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-local\" \"npm run client\"",
"start-local": "nodemon src/server/start.js",
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `allowedHosts` setting is likely to blame.

According to [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverallowedhosts), you might have success with:

```
allowedHosts: ['all']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run your webpack server with https.

For me it was because of the antivirus. Another way to fix it is add your localhost to antivirus exceptions.

Hope it helps!